# Anaconda + Sage Progress?

Tags: anaconda, sage

I run Anaconda under a Windows 10 environment install and would like to run Sage within Anaconda and use Jupyter notebooks.

There are several former / old posts that identify ways to poke around and possibly get it to work or work arounds (Jupyter in Sage). I'm looking for something more simple - an install of Anaconda that includes Sage? Does anyone know if any progress is planned / been made in this area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest SageMath version, 8.8, is on Conda Forge: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/sage/.

Unfortunately, it only works on Linux and MacOS. Windows binaries are planned, but I don't expect them to be available before version 9.*.

For the moment, the simplest way to use SageMath on Windows is still the official installer: https://github.com/sagemath/sage-windows/releases, meaning that you will have two Jupyter servers installed: the one from Anaconda, and the one from SageMath.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to install Cocalc on your computer with Docker. See https://doc.cocalc.com/docker-image.html